# How to use an expression with a generic func lambda in a linq where clause?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

Here's what I have

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache;

public IList<T> Get<T> (Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
{
    return _cache[typeof(T)].Where (criteria);
}
```

The compiler complains (rightly) that it cannot convert from object to T.

How should I proceed from there?

---

### Solution

```
return _cached[type].AsQueryable().Cast<T>().Where (criteria).ToList()
```

The idea is to have the List as an IQueryable and then I could Cast...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the **[`.Cast<>()` Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)**:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache;

public IList<T> Get<T> (Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
{
    return _cache[typeof(T)].Cast<T>().Where (criteria).ToList();
}
```

If you aren't absolutely sure that all elements are of type T, you can use `.OfType<T>()` instead (which skips elements that cannot be cast)

**Edit** You'll also *need to* use `.OfType<T>()` when T is a valuetype (struct).

**Edit** Since your comment mentioned IQueryable, this could help:

```
return _cache[typeof(T)].AsQueryable().Cast<T>().Where (criteria).ToList();
```

Comment: @Stécy Can you... show the code with the error? There must be something else going on

Comment: @Stécy: it really isn't until you add `where T : class` in the method declaration

Comment: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Stécy: `using System.Linq;` should help *or* you have something else than `List<object>` stored in the dictionary? (A list is _not_ IQueryable)

Comment: added the confirmed solution to the answer for future reference

Answer (score 1):

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache;

public IList<T> Get<T> (Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
{
    return _cache[typeof(T)].Cast<T>().Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Gives the following error: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Your answer lead me in the right direction. I only added AsQueryable() before the cast and the compiler is happy now.

Comment: If you include System.Linq that error should go away. It's because there are different extension methods in different namespaces depending on whether you're operating on IQueryable<T> or IEnumerable<T>.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, fixed it:

```
return _cached[type].AsQueryable().Cast<T>().Where (criteria).ToList()
```

The idea is to have the List as an IQueryable and then I could Cast...

Answer (score 0):

may be building the expression dynamically and then compile it is a better option. here is a sample:

```
Expression<Func<TestClass, bool>> query = LambdaBuilder.BuildQuery(queryItems);
Func<TestClass, bool> compiledExpression = query.Compile();
var results = data.Where(compiledExpression);
```

You may read [my article](http://blog.amdaris.com/creating-a-dynamic-linq-query-to-a-collection-with-nested-subqueries-and-regular-expressions/) on it

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need the argument to be of Expression>? Of not this should do the trick:

```
private readonly Dictionary<Type, List<object>> _cache;

public IList<T> Get<T>(Func<T,bool> criteria)
{
    return _cache[typeof(T)].Cast<T>().Where(criteria).ToList();
}
```